# Slow to non-existent MySQL on Fedora?

Tags: mysql, fedora, wordpress

I have a VPS with a few low-traffic personal sites on it, two of which run Wordpress. Occasionally the Wordpress sites just don't want to load. They've taken a minute or more to load. Sometimes I can leave it sitting there for 5 minutes before it just gives up.

What leads me to believe this is a MySQL issue is that static files still load in less than a second when this happens. Since I have MySQL installed on the same server it couldn't be a network latency issue, so I must have something horribly wrong with the configs. This is just an unmodified install of MySQL via Yum on Fedora, so it should be using whatever the defaults are.

Anyone have any idea what could cause something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a locked table.  Run a `show full processlist;` in MySQL when it's not responding.  Check the `.err` log.